# PythonでNone=0と置きたいです

Tags: python

1+None=1というようにNoneを数字的に0と計算の時のみ置きたいのですがどうすればいいでしょうか。0と置けなくても1+None=1が成立すれば大丈夫です。

Comment: 状況がよく判りませんが、bool 型にキャストして計算してもよいかもしれません。`1 + bool(None) == 1`

Answer (score 2):

Noneに対して`+`演算子を使った時の`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'`例外を回避する方法はなく、他の回答のようにある程度冗長な記述が要求されると思います。
ちなみに`None or 0`のようにor演算子を使って0を取得する方法もあります。

```
x, y = 1, None
print((x or 0) + (y or 0)) # 1が返る
```

Answer (score 1):

こういうことでしょうか?

```
def Add(x,y):
    return (x if x else 0) + (y if y else 0)


print(Add(10,1))        # 11
print(Add(10,None))     # 10
print(Add(None,1))      # 1
print(Add(None,None))   # 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Python では出来ないはずです。

- `+` 演算子は左辺の `__add__` や 右辺の `__radd__` を実行します
- `1 + None` の場合、両辺は `int` と `NoneType` です
- これらのタイプ（クラス）は組込み型であり、`__add__` などを変更できません
- よって、この式での `+` の振舞いは変更できません

独自の型を用意すれば、その型に対する `+` の振舞いを変更することは出来ます。

例:

```py
class N(int):

    def __add__(self, other):
        if other == None:
            other = 0
        return N(super().__add__(other))

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)

n0 = N(0)
n1 = N(1)
n2 = N(2)

print(f"{ n1   + None       = }")  # 1
print(f"{ None + n1         = }")  # 1
print(f"{ n1   + 2          = }")  # 3
print(f"{ 1    + n2         = }")  # 3
print(f"{ n1   + n2         = }")  # 3
print(f"{ n0   + 1 + None   = }")  # 1
```

きちんと完成させるならば、他にもメソッドを定義して、[数値型をエミュレートする](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)必要が有ります。[SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) などは、こういったアプローチです。